# Why different server calls are counted counted in same soql limits?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, governorlimits

I have a component container Component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:iteration items="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" var="item">
        <c:testComponent count="{!item}"/><br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

In testComponent i am doing Server call on Init.
My testComponent is

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="TestApex">
    <aura:attribute name="count" type="string" default=""
        access="global" />
    <aura:handler action="{!c.doInit}" name="init" value="{!this}" />
    {!v.count}
</aura:component>
```

my testComponent.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.loadData");
        //action.setParams({ objectId : "003U000001XAtHY", loadOnlyTranscript : true});
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            var returnVal = data.getReturnValue();
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

And my class is

```
public class TestApex {
    @auraenabled
    public static void loadData(){
        list<contact> t = [select id from contact limit 10000];
        return;
    }
}
```

I am previewing my component using a page:-

```
<apex:page title="View" showHeader="true" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:someApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:TestContainerCmp", {}, "lightning", function(cmp) {
        });
    });
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

I am making api calls in different instance of component but still it is giving me below error:

> Too many query rows: 50001.

Why different server calls are counted in same soql limits?

Answer (score 3):

Because Lightning / Aura queues them up client-side and bundles them together into one request - response to save on network traffic. If you'll view Apex debug logs you'll see that as one entry. The hint is in"enqueueAction" name ;)

Some more info:

- Documentation: [Queueing of Server-Side Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_queue.htm)
- SFSE question: [Lightning multiple enqueued actions execute action when all are done](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171073/lightning-multiple-enqueued-actions-execute-action-when-all-are-done)

You might need a shared variable (in helper maybe?) to daisy-chain the calls so when one finishes (in callback method) you clear the variable and one of other components can pick up.

Another idea might be to try using: 
[Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm)

Comment: but in promise can be used if i am making calls in same component. I am making server calls in different component. I will look in another resources.

Comment: ^i will look in resources you shared.