# closeQuickAction does not work using javascript promises

Tags: lightning-aura-components, promises

I came across a [tutorial](https://medium.com/salesforce-zolo/call-apex-or-soql-with-just-one-line-of-code-from-your-lightning-aura-components-3b4b4fe70417) to call Apex or SOQL using few lines of code. This code is using javascript promises in the following fashion:

ApexHelperController.apxc:

```
({
    apex: function(cmp, method, params) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var action = cmp.get("c." + method);
            action.setParams(params);
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                }
                else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    // do something
                }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors && errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                    errors[0].message);
                        reject(errors[0].message);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                        reject("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        });
    },

    ...
})
```

This [helper](https://medium.com/salesforce-zolo/call-apex-or-soql-with-just-one-line-of-code-from-your-lightning-aura-components-3b4b4fe70417) is supposed to abstract code so that we just need to write a few lines of code, for example:

```
helper.apex(component, "search", { searchstr : searchTerm })
.then(function (result) {
  //do something with the result
})
.catch(function (error) {
  //do something about the error
})
```

I am currently using this [helper](https://medium.com/salesforce-zolo/call-apex-or-soql-with-just-one-line-of-code-from-your-lightning-aura-components-3b4b4fe70417); however, the closeQuickAction does not work, my non-working code is:

```
helper.apex(component, "search", { "searchstr" : searchTerm })
.then(function (result) {
      var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
      toastEvent.setParams({
          title: "Success!",
          message: "Request has been sent.",
          type: "success"
      });
      toastEvent.fire();
      $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
      $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
})
.catch(function (error) {
  //do something about the error
})
```

I managed to make my code to work by using the callback directly without the promise but I am still curious why it does not work with the promise, Salesforce did not stay that promises are not supported, right?. My working code for the aura controller is:

```
var action = component.get("c.search");

action.setParams({'sObjectToUpdate': searchTerm});

action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
      var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
      toastEvent.setParams({
          title: "Success!",
          message: "Request has been sent.",
          type: "success"
      });
      toastEvent.fire();
      $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
      $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
    } else {
    }
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: can you put some debug in catch block to see if there is an exception?

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal the "catch" block is not getting trigger, actually the actions refreshView and showToast are working in the "then" block, but not the action closeQuickAction.

Comment: Not sure whats the issue, can you change the sequence, refreshView first and then closeQuickAction then. Documentation suggests same `Firing force:closeQuickAction should be the last thing your quick action handler does.` 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:closeQuickAction/documentation

Comment: I also tried that; however, force:closeQuickAction does not close the current quick action, only works using the callback directly, as shown in my code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the action during the initial promise call and later just fire it:

```
const $closeQuickAction = $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction');

helper.apex(component, "search", { searchstr : searchTerm })
  .finally(function (error) {
    $closeQuickAction.fire();
  })
```

I can only speculate that, only during the initial call, `closeQuickAction` is in reach of the `.get()` call. Apparently, this will be *cleaned up* after the call is done. Immediate callbacks might still be triggered before that and lightning has control over these, but promises run independent and seem to be too late.

Comment: This worked nicely for me when implementing a [multiple-promise pattern](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/171078/61266). I was not able to call an existing component controller function for closing the dialog from my helper, either.